# How to clear a 4 bit shift register with no clear input?

Tags: integrated-circuit, shift-register, register, multiplier

I have 4 bit pipo shift register 74ls95 . It does not have an clear input. Is there any way to clear the register without giving all the parallel inputs as zero. I am using it as an component of shift add multiplier so it needs to be reset whenever the process is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to set the parallel inputs to zero, then the only option is to switch the device into *shift mode*, set *serial input* to zero and generate four *serial clock* pulses.

Check the "mode select" table in the datasheet, how to change mode safely, as switching the mode with certain states of parallel and serial clock inputs leads to undetermined operation of the device.

The safest solution is to switch the mode when both clocks are in low (zero) state.

Having said the above, I still consider, that using the parallel inputs, set temporarily to zero by additional logic, may be a simpler solution...